# Return to current position on the screen when returning from another fragment

Tags: android, fragment, android-recyclerview, onitemclicklistener, onscrolllistener

I have a fragment with list of items displayed in recyclerView. The list could be endlessly scrolled. Each item is clickable and opens another fragment with its description. My question is when I click on any Item and return back, I want to return to the same position on the screen. Now I always return to the top of the screen even if I scroll a lot of items.

```
 private void setScrollListener() {

    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(linearLayoutManager) {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {

            apiCall(pageNumber++, 10);
        }
    });
}
private void listClickListener() {

    if (myAdapter != null) {

        myAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View itemView, int position) {

                Items items = itemsList.get(position);
                setDetailsFragment(items.getDescription());

            }
        });
    }

}

 private void setDetailsFragment(String description) {
    DetailsFragment detailsFragment = new DetailsFragment();
    detailsFragment.setDescription(description);
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frag_container, detailsFragment, "TAG");
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("TAG");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: Please post the code of how you are switching to the next fragment on item click i.e. `setDetailsFragment()` implementation.

Comment: yes sorry, I forgot to add this method

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are replacing your previous fragment.
Add the next fragment instead of replacing if you don't want to reset the previous fragment's state

Change to -

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frag_container, detailsFragment, "TAG");
```

in `setDetailsFragment()`.

Comment: When I changed it to add instead of replace, Main Fragment is still on the screen and DetailsFragment is on top of it.

Comment: Yes of course, that's what .add() does. What is the issue then ? Can you add the screenshot ?

Comment: The issue is the Main Fragment doesn't go away.  I have list of images and text from the Details Fragment is on top of the list

Comment: The issue is with the layout files. Can you post those ?

Comment: Layouts are fine. I have a framelayout in my activity_main.xml which is a fragment container for both of my fragments

Comment: Doesn't matters.  You have to the set non-transparent background to the details fragment layout, to hide the main fragment view.

Comment: It does this solve problem. But now i have issues when i press back. The backPress button keeps reloading the main fragment before I exit the app